# SSRS Forms Authentication - Report Builder Login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I'm using SSRS 2005, with custom forms authentication module.  That works great.  But the report builder prompts for credentials, is there a way to get around this?  Is this a configurability thing?

Thanks.